# XCode 4 (Assembla) SVN Repository "Unable to load revisions"

Tags: svn, xcode4, assembla

I've been trying unsuccessfully to connect to an https assembla svn repository with the new xcode 4 IDE for an iPhone project I'm working on.

I was able to connect just fine with the last version of xcode (3?), and with other svn apps. I'm using the same repo address and credentials, so I'm baffled as to why this doesn't work.

I also tried loading in a working copy of the repo, and it cannot connect either.

The one error message that comes up is "Unable to load revisions"

Any tips?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a lot of links, but no solution posted directly here, so I'll do it.

The reason Xcode4 does this is that it tries to log you into the SVN server with your mac credentials. When that fails, it basically just hangs and fails. The best solution I've seen so far is this:

open a terminal

If you don't have the project out do this:

`>svn checkout SERVER_PATH FOLDER_PATH_TO_PUT_THE_PROJECT`

It will then ask you for password for the mac username, you just write anything or nothing and press enter.

it will then fail and ask you for a username. Enter the correct one and then the password when it asks.

The project will be checked out, but you can just close the terminal window and delete the folder again if you want. Xcode4 will now connect without a hitch. :)

Comment: Hi i have done the same thing for this command:
svn checkout http://simple-iphone-image-processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
But it says host not found.. please help i want to checkout code from google code repository and i am using Xcode 4.3.2

Comment: Server path should have the preceding svn:// on it I believe.

Comment: I just tested it out. You have to have http:// at the beginning and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://forum.assembla.com/forums/2-Subversion/topics/2881-SVN-don-t-remember-my-credentials#post_9172

This helps me with same issue

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem when opening a project I had previously checked out using another SVN client (Versions). So I fired up Wireshark to look at the SVN traffic and saw that it was an HTTP authentication problem.

I opened up the Xcode Organizer window (Shift-⌘-2) and deleted the autogenerated repository bookmarks. Then I added my own fresh bookmark. That fixed it.

You could also try deleting the repository bookmark in the organizer and just reopen the project. That seemed to work for another of my projects. It asked me for my password and everything started working.

And don't forget to tell the organizer the paths to trunk, branches and tags. It can't guess those from a local checkout, and setting them up will enable you to do branching, merging and tagging from within Xcode 4.

It is probably worth noting that Xcode 4 crashed on me about 5 times during this process. I think it is still early days for the new and improved SCM integration. So good luck!

Answer (score 1):

See this post:  [xcode 4 with subversion SVN server–Tips](http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/iphone/xcode-4-with-subversion-svn-servertips/)  TYVM InteractiveWebs!  Xcode4 and SVN are playing nicely together once again.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found! I followed the instructions on the page, and it cleared up all my issues: http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4svn-could-not-authenticate-to.html

Essentially, it seems that Subversion or Xcode was caching a wrong username/password combo.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue simply replacing the IP address with the NetBios name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; was working in XCode 3 blah blah...

I followed all the instructions here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376422/xcode-4-svn-working/6841241#6841241) but still it was hanging.

The problem was that my svn username and my mac OS username and password were the same. Once I'd changed the name of my svn user it worked!

Hope this prevents anyone else spending a day's work on this

Answer (score 0):

There is another change in xcode 4 that can contribute to svn connectivity problems and that is that the name lookup for host names only uses a dns lookup and will not see any hosts in the /etc/host file. This impacts more than svn connectivity. An example is in the iphone simulator if you are attempting to connect to a local (not in dns but in the /etc/host file) system you will not be able to see it. This would imply that issues around name lookup would impact other areas like git … The workaround is very gross you must use ip addresses in the URI. Unfortunately the xcode team decided it would be unimportant to surface this information either in the docs or in some type of error log or message. A simple test is if you can ping the host but nslookup cannot find it then xcode will also not be able to see it.

Comment: I can ping and nslookup my local SVN server using it's name but when I try and add a repository in XCode it says the host is unreachable though the IP address works ok. It's best not to use IP addresses for SVN in case it changes. I think I'll use Cornerstone for the moment.