# Unable to connect to svn repository with XCode 4

Tags: svn, xcode4

After installing XCode 4 I went to the Organizer window to try to verify that the svn repositories that were set up in XCode 3 were recognized.  The repositories were there but whenever I clicked on one I would always get the 'busy-wait' spinner.  Thinking that XCode 4 didn't properly import the repository information, I went through the steps to re-create one of the repositories from scratch.  I'm pretty sure I've input all the details correctly and I know I'm using the right password, but still all I'm seeing is the 'busy-wait' spinner.  Beyond this, I don't know anything more about what the problem might be.  Is there a log somewhere to which XCode writes error information related to connecting to svn repositories?  I've read a few questions here related to problems with svn and XCode 4 but so far I haven't found anything like what I'm seeing.

When I restart XCode I'm seeing a dialog saying 'Could not connect to server'.  Could this be related to my problems connecting to svn?  What other server could XCode be trying to connect to?

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hade the same problem when we changed the IP address of our Subversion server. Are you using the the https protocol to connect by any chance? If so and your SSL certificate is internally generated xCode is not accepting it.

The solution I found was to:

### ONE

Rename my local source code checkout folder AND back it up (to be extra sure)

### TWO

Create a new local source code checkout folder with the original name

### THREE

Checkout my projects again to the new folder using the svn command line utility in terminal which will show you the message:

- The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
  fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!

but you have the option to permanently accept the "fingerprint". Once checked out open the project in xCode and go to the Organizer window and you should see your repository there with a green light!

Naturally now you have to migrate across any modified source from you renamed or backed up original which is a bit of a headache. Don't copy the project file though or it will mess things up.

### FOUR

May not apply in your case but I added an entry to the hosts file so if our repository moves again I won't have this problem!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What did it was using the svn command line to check out the project and then adding the local project to Xcode.  Just doing this worked for one account.  However, for another account I needed to restart Xcode in order for

Answer (score 4):

svn might not be working due to the cache containing a wrong password.

Use spotlight and open 'terminal' 
Type 'svn co --username=myname svn://www.mydomain.com:port/svn/myrepository/ .

svn will now ask you for the password - enter it. 
Now switch back to the repository browser in xcode4 and it will be recognized.