# SVN not working after updating to xcode 4.1 for snow leopard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, svn, xcode4

I have recently updated my xcode to version 4.1 for snow leopard, but after that my life became miserable and all the repositories in Organizer are unable to connect and show red icons.

Anybody has any idea how to fix that???

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this:

1.open a terminal

2.type 'svn list svn://~~~paths'

ie. "NJW-Mac:~ bluepin$ svn list svn://192.168.0.184/BMA"

3.You will need to enter PCUserPassword,svnUserID,svnUserPassword

4.U should see output from the svn list command which means you were able to connect to the SVN server

5.return to xcode4

6.try again your job(connect Repositories)

from [Xcode 4 + SVN = working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376422/xcode-4-svn-working)

Answer (score 1):

Is it the IP addr in the settings of svn? I had the same problem on lion at the begin. so pls try to input your svn server name to replace the ip addr, it's will be work.
If you did not get the name of your server, you could set a new name in the /etc/hosts file by yourself. Such as "192.168.1.10 iOS_SVN_Server".