# Unable to load revisions SVN message after OS X Lion and Xcode 4.3.2 upgrade

Tags: xcode, svn, osx-lion, revision

I upgraded to OS X Lion and Xcode 4.3.2. After the upgrade, when I open Organizer and select the Root folder for any of our SVN projects, I immediately get an "Unable to load revisions" message and I cannot see the folder information. I am entering my credentials correctly and tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309792/xcode-4-assembla-svn-repository-unable-to-load-revisions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376422/xcode-4-svn-working) and it still does not work. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. I use MacPorts to manage the installation of open source software, like SVN in this case. According to the MacPorts [migration](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) guide, it is recommended to reinstall Xcode and MacPorts after an OS upgrade, if there are any issues. So I uninstalled all my ports and then MacPorts according to this [guide](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html). I then installed the latest version of MacPorts for OS X Lion from the [MacPorts download directory](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/). Finally, I did a [self update](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html#using.port.selfupdate) of MacPorts, just in case, and [re-installed SVN](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/Subversion). I was then able to see all SVN projects in Organizer.