# Configure SVN in Xcode 4.4.1 with Mountain Lion

Tags: svn, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

When I try to set a repository in Xcode 4.4.1 I get this error:

[image: error screenshot]

On Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2 all works fine, though.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Try the solutions posted in the similar StackOverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5309792/1641565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Xcode Preference*. 
Click on tab *Downloads* and select *Components* flag.

Then installa ***Command line tools*** and use *SVN* from *Terminal*.

Hope this help!